# How to create responsive image maps with tooltips?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, tooltip, imagemap

I have created a JS-based tooltip that works on image maps. The problem I am having though is that it does not work on small laptop screens or if the browser window is minimized. I would really appreciate some help on this one.

Here is a codepen sample, https://codepen.io/ArshRai/pen/LwRGvZ

Image Map

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-350-350-5.jpg" usemap="#foodmap">
<map id="#foodmap" name="foodmap">
  <area class="area" shape="rect" coords="0,0,170,100" href="#" target="_self" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, &lt;br&gt; sea no laoreet noluisse suavitate, mei melius laoreet ne. Id modus dicta neglegentur pro.  Prima delicatissimi ex sed, est in iriure epicurei consequuntur. Ne malis nulla luptatum vis. Vim quodsi lucilius intellegam no." />

  <area class="area" shape="rect" coords="187,0,342,188" href="#" target="_self" title="Carrot" />

  <area class="area" shape="rect" coords="169,182,350,350" href="#" target="_self" title="Cucumber" />

  <area class="area" shape="poly" coords="78,133,158,182,162,349,0,349,0,283" href="#" target="_self" title="Red Pepper"/>
</map>
```

CSS

```
#tooltip {
 background: #607D8B;
 color:#ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #009688;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 z-index:9999;
}
```

JS

```
(function () {
  var ID = "tooltip", CLS_ON = "tooltip_ON", FOLLOW = true,
  DATA = "_tooltip", OFFSET_X = 20, OFFSET_Y = 10,
  showAt = function (e) {
   var ntop = e.pageY + OFFSET_Y, nleft = e.pageX + OFFSET_X;
   $("#" + ID).html($(e.target).data(DATA)).css({
   position: "absolute", top: ntop, left: nleft
    }).show();
  };
   $(document).on("mouseenter", "*[title]", function (e) {
    $(this).data(DATA, $(this).attr("title"));
    $(this).removeAttr("area[title]").addClass(CLS_ON);
    $("<div id='" + ID + "' />").appendTo("body");
    showAt(e);
    });
    $(document).on("mouseleave", "." + CLS_ON, function (e) {
     $(this).attr("title", $(this).data(DATA)).removeClass(CLS_ON);
     $("#" + ID).remove();
    });
    if (FOLLOW) { $(document).on("mousemove", "." + CLS_ON, showAt); }
}());
```

I just can't figure out what I need to do to make it work on minimized browsers and small screens.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your coords in percentage you can just set a

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

To handle the scale correctly.

If you can't have your coords in percent, you'll have to play with  window `resize` event to scale your image with `transform: scale(...)` property in order to keep your coord positions.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks! I can change the coords to percentage, but that will be a lot of manual work. I will try to figure out the `resize` event...Hmmmm It will be a tricky one for me.

Comment: You're welcome. If not too much work I would definitely go for percentage values.